# create Azure VM cannot select "europe"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to create Azure VM with public static IP.

Here is the issues I encountered:
I have a "VS professional MSDN subscription" which gave me 45e/month Azure credit. 
I log into Azure portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) with MSDN subscription enabled account to create new virtual machine, in "REGION/AFFINITY GROUP" option, only "central us", "south central us", "east asia", "south east asia", "japan west" is available, while I would like to create VM in "north europe"

If I log into Azure preview portal (https://portal.azure.com), I can create VM in "north europe" but `New-AzureReservedIP` powershell command is not working with `-Location "North Europe", only locations avaialabe from old portal region list allows (such as "south central us")

Comment: Just to understand what you try to achieve. Why you use New-AzureReservedIP?

Comment: I plan to reserve a public IP and use it for new VMs. Without so, each time VM reboot will get a new public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft prevented my account to create VM in European regions.
Their tech support enabled it after internal team discussion.
Now I can create VMs as I want.

Thus, it is an issue in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

In "classic" mode **New-AzureReservedIP** create a new IP address for  your cloud service. After the reserved IP has been created, you can only associate it with the cloud service.

When it can be useful?

If all of the virtual machines in a cloud service are in the StoppedDeallocated state (or deleted), the public IP
address of the cloud service is lost. You can mitigate this by using a reserved IP address hosting your virtual machines.

Now if you use https://portal.azure.com and "Resource Manager" for creating your VMs, you can configure the public IP for the VM at creation time or change after.

At creation time
[image]

It seems that static IP address currently is not supported. I have tried to create an static PublicIP address with `New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress` but its support only dynamic type. When I set "static" for the switch `-AllocationMethod Static` its return me this error

```
Currently this 
configuration is not supported. Network interfaces can use only dynamic public IPs.
```

Comment: But the public IP address is not static, right? I would like to have a static public IP for the virtual machine during the initiation.

Comment: if you try use New-AzureReservedIP to reserve static IP and assign it to new VMs, it will work. static IP cannot be assigned to existing Vms.  Anyway your update seems not relevant to the question

Comment: New-AzureReservedIP create static IP address for your Cloud Service and not for your VM... The Set-AzurePublicIP cmdlet is used to add a public IP to a specific
virtual machine but not the VIP of the cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

In the ARM CLI, you can use the following command to create a static public IP in the resource group "momentarybehaviorrg" (which must already exist) with name "myipname" in location "North Europe":

```
azure network public-ip create -g momentarybehaviorrg -n myipname -l "North Europe" -a Static
```

For more info, take a look at the documentation with the following command:

```
azure network public-ip create -h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can script all the vm creation process via powershell, this include the creation of resource group, the subnet, the vnet, the public ip, network security group, the storage and much more.

You can attach all vm resources to one resource group and by doing this you can easly delete the vm and realted resources by executing one command line.

#### Install and import AzureRM

In order to use and execute the below commands we need to install and import the AzureRM powershell module if we don't already have it, if you already have it you can skip this section.

PS: You need elevated privileges to install modules from PowerShell Gallery

```
`Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber`
```

By default, the PowerShell gallery is not configured as a trusted repository for PowerShellGet. The first time you use PSGallery, the following message is displayed:

```
Untrusted repository

    You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change
    its InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet.

    Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
    [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "N"):
    So, don't worry about this message.
```

Once installed, you can import AzureRM by running the following command:

```
Import-Module AzureRM
```

Finnaly, to finish with this section we need to connect to Azure account, simply execute this command and you we be prompted:

```
# Connect to Azure with an interactive dialog for sign-in
Connect-AzureRmAccount
```

[image] [image]

#### Create a resource group

A resource group is a logical container in which Azure resources are deployed and managed.
From your SDK, run the following code block to create a resource group:

```
# Create variables to store the location and resource group names.
    $location = "francecentral"
    $ResourceGroupName = "resource-group-1"

    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $location
```

#### Create storage resources

Create a storage account to store the output of boot diagnostics.

```
# Create variables to store the storage account name and the storage account SKU information
    $StorageAccountName = "msstorage01"
    $SkuName = "Standard_LRS"

    # Create a new storage account
    $StorageAccount = New-AzureRMStorageAccount `
      -Location $location `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Type $SkuName `
      -Name $StorageAccountName

    Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount `
      -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName `
      -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

#### Create networking resources

Create a VNet (virtual network), subnet, and a public IP address. Creating these Azure resources help us providing the network connectivity to our VM.

```
# Create a the subnet configuration
    $subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
      -Name subNet-1 `
      -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24
```

#### Create the virtual network

```
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Location $location `
      -Name vNet-1 `
      -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 `
      -Subnet $subnetConfig
```

#### Create a public IP address and specify a DNS name

```
$publicip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Location $location `
      -AllocationMethod Static `
      -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4 `
      -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)"
```

#### Create a NSG (network security group ) and a NSG rule

The NSG secures our VM by using inbound and outbound rules.

Now, we need to create an inbound rule for port 3389 to allow incoming RDP (Remote Desktop) connections and an inbound rule for port 80 to let our VM receive the incoming web traffic.

Create an inbound NSG rule for the 3389 port

```
# Create an inbound NSG rule for the 3389 port
    # This rule will allow us to connect to the VM via an RDP connection
    $nsgrdprule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
      -Name nsg-rdp-rule `
      -Protocol Tcp `
      -Direction Inbound `
      -Priority 1000 `
      -SourceAddressPrefix * `
      -SourcePortRange * `
      -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
      -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
      -Access Allow
```

Create an inbound network security group rule for port 80

```
# This rule will allow the VM to receive incoming web connections via the port 80


$nsgwebrule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
      -Name nsg-inbound-www-rule `
      -Protocol Tcp `
      -Direction Inbound `
      -Priority 1001 `
      -SourceAddressPrefix * `
      -SourcePortRange * `
      -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
      -DestinationPortRange 80 `
      -Access Allow
```

Create the NSG (network security group)

```
# This will wrap up previously created rules (nsg-web-rule and nsg-rdp-rule) within an NSG
    $nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Location $location `
      -Name nsg-1 `
      -SecurityRules $nsgrdprule,$nsgwebrule 

    # This command will create a VNC (virtual network card) and associate it with public IP address and NSG
    $nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface `
      -Name nic-1 `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Location $location `
      -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id `
      -PublicIpAddressId $publicip.Id `
      -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

    # Define a credential object to store the username and password for the VM
    $UserName='ali.mselmi'
    $Password='P@ssword123'| ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
    $Credential=New-Object PSCredential($UserName,$Password)
```

#### Create the VM configuration object

```
$VmName = "VirtualMachinelatest"
    $VmSize = "Standard_A1"
    $VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig `
      -VMName $VmName `
      -VMSize $VmSize

    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem `
      -VM $VirtualMachine `
      -Windows `
      -ComputerName "MainComputer" `
      -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent

    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage `
      -VM $VirtualMachine `
      -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" `
      -Offer "WindowsServer" `
      -Skus "2016-Datacenter" `
      -Version "latest"

    # Sets the operating system disk properties on a VM.
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk `
      -VM $VirtualMachine `
      -CreateOption FromImage | `
      Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -Enable |`
      Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id
```

#### Create the VM

Finnaly we can create the VM deployment configuration.

```
# Create the VM.
    New-AzureRmVM `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -Location $location `
      -VM $VirtualMachine
```

We can check the VM creation via the Azure portal:
[image]

#### Connect to the VM

To do a remote access into the VM that we created in the previous step, we need its public IP address also previously set up.

To do that, we just need to run the following command and get the public IP address:

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName | Select IpAddress
```

[image]

Now, we can do a remote desktop access after creating a Remote Desktop session with the VM, just you need replace the IP address with the publicIPAddress of your VM.
When prompted, you can login by using your credentials used when creating the VM.

```
`mstsc /v publicIpAddress`
```

[image]

## Connect to the Azure VM with an RDP, SSH or Bastion

You can connect to the VM via RDP, SSH or Bastion, you just need to click to the created VM via Azure portal and then click connect.
[image]

#### Delete the VM

We can use the following command to remove the resource group that contains the VM and its related resources:

```
Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup `
      -Name $ResourceGroupName
```

#### Final words...

The advantage of scripting the entire VM creation process is that often we don't need to create a single VM, but to create several, creating a script for the process gives us the flexibility to customize the VMs creation at large-scale.

#### Original blog post

[Create a Windows Server virtual machine with PowerShell](https://mselmi.net/create-a-windows-server-virtual-machine-with-powershell/)